# Need help understanding function notation

Tags: integration, functions

I just finished my test and I have no idea what one of the questions was. No academic dishonesty here, I already got graded and I got 75%, but I am just stuck on that exercise and have no idea how to understand the function in the question.

It was supposed to be an integration of a function, and it looked like this:

$$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; (x,y) \rightarrow x$$

I dont even remember the teacher using this notation, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The function is the function that maps a point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ to its $x$-coordinate; in other words, it is projection onto the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ means that $f$ is a mapping from 2d space over real number to 1d space over real number, e.g. an ordered pair (a 2-tuple) of real numbers $(x,y)$ to a single real number. In your example it maps the tuple to its first component, as described by $(x,y) \rightarrow x$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I think I’m starting to understand. Does that mean that my function would just look like this: f(x,y)=x or f=x?

Comment: The first of those, not the second. You should not have been exposed to new notation for the first time on an exam.

Comment: Thanks Xichu and thank you Ethan Bolker!